# what is the proper way to use proxies with requests in python

Tags: python, python-requests, proxy, urllib3, proxies

Requests is not honoring the proxies flag.

There is something I am missing about making a request over a proxy with python requests library.

If I enable the OS system proxy, then it works, but if I make the request with just requests module proxies setting, the remote machine will not see the proxy set in requests, but will see my real ip, it is as if not proxy was set.

The bellow example will show this effect, at the time of this post the bellow proxy is alive but any working proxy should replicate the effect.

```
import requests

proxy ={
  'http:': 'https://143.208.200.26:7878',
  'https:': 'http://143.208.200.26:7878'
}
data = requests.get(url='http://ip-api.com/json', proxies=proxy).json()
print('Ip: %s\nCity: %s\nCountry: %s' % (data['query'], data['city'], data['country']))
```

I also tried changing the proxy_dict format:

```
proxy ={
          'http:': '143.208.200.26:7878',
          'https:': '143.208.200.26:7878'
       }
```

But still it has not effect.

I am using:
-Windows 10
-python 3.9.6
-urllib 1.25.8

Many thanks in advance for any response to help sort this out.

Comment: seem like the host you calling to have another way to detect your real ip from the request(maybe they using `X_FORWARDED_FOR`), otherwise your way of using proxies in request look correct. Try using another free proxy address to see if it working, maybe it's because the proxies you using isn't correct or not running

Comment: thanks for responding, I tested this already with other sites, and still the same effect

Comment: You proxy dictionary seems to have an unusual construction where http directs to https and *vice versa*. Also, does the proxy require authentication?

Comment: It does not require authentication, already tested globally in the system and it works

Comment: @DiegoSuarez remove the colon from the keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok is working yea !!! .
The credits for solving this goes to (Olvin Rogh) Thanks Olvin for your help and pointing out my problem. I was adding colon ":" inside the keys
This code is working now.

```
PROXY = {'https': 'https://143.208.200.26:7878',
         'http': 'http://143.208.200.26:7878'}


with requests.Session() as session:
    session.proxies = PROXY
    r = session.get('http://ip-api.com/json')
    print(json.dumps(r.json(), indent=2))
```